# Date format trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

```
set dateformat yyyy-mm-dd;

insert into orders(order_id, customer_id, order_status, order_date, required_date, shipped_date, store_id, staff_id)

Values

(1, 259, 4, '2016-01-01', '2016-01-03', '2016-01-03', 1, 2),
(2, 1212, 4, '2016-01-01', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-03', 2, 6),
(3, 523, 4, '2016-01-02', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-03', 2, 7),
(4, 175, 4, '2016-01-03', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', 1, 3),
(5, 1324, 4, '2016-01-03', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-06', 2, 6),
(6, 94, 4, '2016-01-04', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-53', 2, 6),
(7, 324, 4, '2016-01-04', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-05', 2, 6),
(8, 1204, 4, '2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-05', 2, 7),
(9, 60, 4, '2016-01-05', '2016-01-08', '2016-01-08', 1, 2),
(10, 442, 4, '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-06', 2, 6),
(11, 1326, 4, '2016-01-05', '2016-01-08', '2016-01-07', 2, 7);

select order_id, customer_id, order_status, order_date, required_date, shipped_date, store_id, staff_id from orders
```

IT says:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 50
> Incorrect syntax near '-'.

how do I fix this error?

I tried deleting the hwole thing and retyping and seeing how to fix the solution online.

Comment: The tags are there to direct the question to people who can answer it. Add tags that indicate which rdbms youre using.

Comment: `2016-01-53` is not a valid date.

Comment: Does your sql server allow multi insert?

Answer (score 1):

The error about the `-` character is for the `set dateformat` statement, not the literal values later in the SQL.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Valid parameters are mdy, dmy, ymd, ydm, myd, and dym.

Therefore the `set dateformat` code should look like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
```

However, this excerpt from the documentation is also worth noting:

> Some character string formats, for example ISO 8601, are interpreted independently of the DATEFORMAT setting.

The documentation is not more specific than this about which exact formats might apply or when. People who have [dug deeply into this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166772/5469) have determined the better strategy here is matching the input data to SQL Server's preferred format, which for date-only values with no time component is the **unseparated** ISO8601 variant (likely for historical reasons).

Therefore you should do this:

```
insert into orders
    (order_id, customer_id, order_status, order_date, required_date, shipped_date, store_id, staff_id)

VALUES

( 1,  259, 4, '20160101', '20160103', '20160103', 1, 2),
( 2, 1212, 4, '20160101', '20160104', '20160103', 2, 6),
( 3,  523, 4, '20160102', '20160105', '20160103', 2, 7),
( 4,  175, 4, '20160103', '20160104', '20160105', 1, 3),
( 5, 1324, 4, '20160103', '20160106', '20160106', 2, 6),
( 6,   94, 4, '20160104', '20160107', '20160153', 2, 6),
( 7,  324, 4, '20160104', '20160107', '20160105', 2, 6),
( 8, 1204, 4, '20160104', '20160105', '20160105', 2, 7),
( 9,   60, 4, '20160105', '20160108', '20160108', 1, 2),
(10,  442, 4, '20160105', '20160106', '20160106', 2, 6),
(11, 1326, 4, '20160105', '20160108', '20160107', 2, 7);

select order_id, customer_id, order_status, order_date, required_date, shipped_date, store_id, staff_id 
from orders
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using the formate "yyyy-mm-dd", which is common.
but what happens, if your SQL server is expecting a different date format?

Then show the error message called " **Incorrect syntax near '-'** ".Try different date formats.

Ensure that your database compatibility level supports the date format you are using. some databases might have specific configurations related to date formatting.

I hope my answer is helpful.